# Laravel Eloquent - Save/Update Related One-To-Many Relationship Data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have an entity Set that has many Items in it. So, when updating the sets, the form includes the field to update it's item too. I've done it and it's working well, but I'm not sure if it's the correct and most efficient/elegant way to do it. Here's my code:

```
        $set->fill(Input::all());

        foreach (Input::get('course') as $course_id => $content) {
            $item = $set->items->filter(function ($item) use ($course_id) {
                return ($item->course_id == $course_id);
            })->first();
            $item->content = $content;
            $set->items()->save($item);
        }
        $set->save();
```

As you can see, for each items, I looped through all the input (which may vary on how many it has), filter it, and save the value 1 by 1. So a query is executed for every iteration. I use filter so that it doesn't have to do a query for every check.

So my question is, is there a more efficient/elegant way to do this? Something like saveMany() maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method ***saveMany*** like this:

```
        $set->fill(Input::all());
        $items = array();
        foreach (Input::get('course') as $course_id => $content) {
            $item = $set->items->filter(function ($item) use ($course_id) {
                return ($item->course_id == $course_id);
            })->first();
            $item->content = $content;
            $items[] = $item;
        }

        $set->items()->saveMany($items);
        $set->save();
```

As pointed in related models of [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I guess that you don't need a specific Collection object to pass to saveMany(). We can just use simple array like you did. Tested and verified it's working. Thanks.